# structures programm not working correctly

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I wanted to try the function malloc and pointer to structures but when i compile and run the programm it only prints the first and the second input but the third input doesnt gets printed and i think its a buffer overflow or something, i cant find it where there is a problem

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define max 30


char *NL(char *string);

int main()
{


    struct menschen
    {
        char name_usa[max];
        int anzahl;
        char Anfuerer[max];
    };
    int f = 0;
    char *input;
    input = malloc(max);
    struct menschen *mensch;
    mensch = malloc(sizeof(struct menschen));

    printf("Bitte eingeben wer der Praesident der USA ist:  ");
    fgets(input, max, stdin);
    NL(input);
    strcpy(mensch->name_usa, input);

    printf("Bitte eingeben, wie viele menschen auf der welt leben:  ");
    scanf("%i", &f);
    mensch->anzahl = f;

    printf("Bitte eingeben wer der typen ist:  ");
    fgets(input, max, stdin);
    NL(input);
    strcpy(mensch->Anfuerer, input);


    printf("Der Name des Praesidenten der USA ist %s. Die Anzahl der Menschen die Auf der erde leben, ist %i. Der Name des typen ist %s.", mensch->name_usa, mensch->anzahl, mensch->Anfuerer);

    free(mensch);
    free(input);

    return 0;
}

char *NL(char *string)
{
    char *string2 = string;
    while(*string2)
    {
        if(*string2 == '\n')
            *string2 = '\0';
        string2++;
    }

    return string;
}
```

The input is
Bitte eingeben wer der Praesident der USA ist:  Biden
Bitte eingeben, wie viele Menschen auf der welt leben:  710
Bitte eingeben wer der Typ ist:  Justus (i cant do a input, the input is ending at the second one)

The expectet output is:
Der Name des Praesidenten der USA ist Biden. Die Anzahl der Menschen die Auf der erde leben, ist 710. Der Name des typen ist .

But the output i want is:
Der Name des Praesidenten der USA ist Biden. Die Anzahl der Menschen die Auf der erde leben, ist 710. Der Name des types ist Justus

Comment: Please give the exact input, expected result and actual result.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is scanf doesn't consume the newline.
I suggest you use fgets and then sscanf or strtol to read an integer on a line.